# How can I make the pixels of each intensity value in an individual list in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, pixel

I need to make the pixels with the same intensity value in a list so I will get a list of lists of intensity values and each list has the pixels with the same intensity value.

```
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import asarray
from scipy import ndimage, misc, stats
import cv2


### Load the image 

img  = nib.load('input_dir/FLAIR1.nii.gz')
img_data = img.get_fdata()
imgs = img_data[:, :, 23]

rows, col = imgs.shape
my_nlist = [[] for k in range(y.shape[0])]
print(im_arr[2,2])
for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, col): 
        pixel = imgs[i, j]
        for k in range(y.shape[0]):
            if pixel == [k]:               
                my_nlist[k].append(pixel)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it harder on yourself than you have to :) this is exactly what a histogram is meant for!

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2 as cv # You won't be needing cv2, it is just needed to create this example

img = cv.imread('dir/to/img', 0) # notice the grayscale flag
hist, bins, _ = plt.hist(img) # hist contains the list of pixels with the same intensity for each intensity in the picture
plt.show() # in case you want to visualize it
```

This is what it will look like:

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you I just get the error in my code and fix it. I don't need the simple histogram I need to get each intensity values in a list to get their gradient magnitude values and then the CDF of each value i.

Comment: ... the variable `hist` contains exactly that (intensity values (and their count) for each intensity found in the image)

Comment: The result of hist is a NumPy array that counts the number of pixels for each intensity value. But I need the list of values to know how each value transforms into another gradient value. Because when I apply the Sobel mask to get the gradient values the merge of values transform and I need a 2D function that plot the CDF of the gradient with the original pixel values.